# Cannot Link GLSL Program

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I can't get the following Code to work. I want to render the triangle I describe in `position[]`.

The program gives me sometimes a shader compile error or a program linking error and sometimes even both without me changing the code in between.

Program:

```
Window window(TITLE, WIDTH, HEIGHT) // Context and glew gets init here

float position[] = {-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                     0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                     0.0,  0.5, 0.0};

// Shader program gets init
sID = glCreateProgram();
vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_Vertex_SHADER);
fragShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, vertexShaderCodeString); // The Code strings are valid, I printed them out
glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, fragShaderCodeString);

glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
glCompileShader(fragShaderID);
shaderDidCompileCheck(vertexShaderID); // A function I wrote that checks for errors
shaderDidCompileCheck(fragShaderID);

glAttachShader(sID, vertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(sID, fragShaderID);

glLinkProgram(sID);
programDidLinkCheck(); // A function I wrote that checks for errors
glValidateProgram(sID);

glUseProgram(sID);
glBindAttribLocation(sID, 0, "position");
glUseProgram(0);

// Defining VBOs and VAOs
int bufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * 3 * sizeof(float), mDataPtr, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // I have 3 vertices with 3 coordinates each
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

int vaoID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL); // I Want to load it to the index 0 of the VAO, the vertex size is 3, the data type is GL_FLOAT
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

// Main loop
while(!window.close()) {
    glClearColor(0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(sID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(mWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 410
in vec3 position;
out vec3 color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    color = vec3(position.x + 0.5, 0.5, position.y + 0.5);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 410
in vec3 color;
out vec4 outputColor;

void main() {
    outputColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Your linker or shader  must return an error code. What is that error code?

Comment: You must do `glBindAttribLocation` before `glLinkProgram`. I would recomend [www.learnopengl.com](http://learnopengl.com/)

Comment: Well, the error Code I get is just a default string that I wrote myself.

Comment: Already tried to `glBindAttribLocation` before `glLinkProgram`, but it ddint work. thanks for your help though.

Comment: "glAttatchShader" is not a GL function. Maybe you meant "glAttachShader".

Comment: There's an entire (mostly) human-readable log generated by the compiler and linker. Query that (info log) instead of blindly guessing these things.

Comment: Also, considering the API takes 4 parameters for `glShaderSource`, you've still not pasted the correct code. It expects an array of zero-terminated strings (or barring that, an array of strings and an array of lengths).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few typos in your code. You write "vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_Vertex_SHADER)", but macros are indicated in capital letters -> "GL_VERTEX_SHADER". Try glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, vertexShaderCodeString, NULL), instead of passing 3 parametrs.

Answer (score 0):

How did you saved your sourcecode of the shaders ? Make shure to have `\n`
after the version declaration, otherwise you will end up having the code in the same line as the #, which is bad.

Comment: I checked the string, everything is okay with it....Well, I guess imma start the whole Project from scratch and download new graphics drivers...